# Is there a way to enable OpenCL C++ bindings to throw exceptions for all errors?

Tags: c++, exception, opencl

As per subject looks like the C++ API for OpenCL does not always `throw` in case of errors.

For example, one has to check return values and/or error code when invoking `cl::Program::build`, `cl::Kernel::setArg` or passing and error code pointer (which is optional) when constructing `cl::Kernel`.

Is there a way to have the *always throw on error* behaviour enabled?
Maybe a preprocessor macro or something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of this writing, the current version is OpenCL 2.2. As of this version, there is no [preprocessor macro](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/wiki/Predefined-macros-in-OpenCL-(standard-and-proprietary)) neither [pragmas](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/EXTENSION.html) nor build-time flags for that kind of *always `throw` on error* behavior.  However, the [source code](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/) can be found in the Khronos Group repository at GitHub, if you **really** want that behavior your best bet is to add it yourself or request it.